# take picture from device screen content (not a view) programmatically in android app

Tags: android

i'm developing an app and need to make Activity that take snapshot from current content of device screen.
note: i dont want take picture from my activity content or some view, i want take a picture from all of device screen content. ( like home screen or every applications that are on foreground). i googled many times and search so much.

there is an example code:

```
View screen = (View)findViewById(R.id.screen);
screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bmScreen = screen.getDrawingCache();
showBitmap(bmScreen); // function that show my bitmap image
```

with this code can capture my activity's view, but i dont want capture onlye my activity. i want make a thread that capture device screen with all of its contents.
can everybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, mostly for security reasons. If this were possible, some rogue app could silently capture and send somewhere screenshots of everything you are doing on your device.

Why this is not available to non-system apps:

Android let's SDK applications do certain things, and explicitly forbids others. An app is not supposed to read another app's data and similarly an app cannot capture another app's screen. Google has explicitly said that third party apps are not supposed to take screencaptures of other apps. The lack of screen capture API's is a deliberate decision, not an omission. ICS offers screenshot functionality, but it is implemented by the system, and requires a hardware trigger in order to make sure it cannot be started or accessed by third party apps.

While there are ways to do this, they either require root (to read the graphics buffer directly, which is device-dependent), or are not guaranteed to work on all devices/versions.

Comment: whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?  so there are some app's that do this. so, how this apps written!!??

Comment: They most probably require root access and try to read the graphics buffer directly. Which may or may not work, and is probably device-dependent. What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: just like i explained before i want to make a picture from my android device screen. just take picture to use that picture for making help topics for a special program or anything.. this is not important that device must be root or not. i if there is any code that work on rooted device i need it. not rooted device are not important for me. is there any sample code?

Comment: Use Eclipse, the DDMS perspective allows you take screenshots of the whole screen. That should do fine for creating help pages.

Comment: thanks nikoly but i want develop an app that do this in android device without using any computer or something... there is no way? realy?

Comment: @NikolayElenkov After seeing the statement from a representative of Google, your answer is much more correct than I previously though and did not deserve the downvote. Could you edit, so I may remove it?